# Triple monitor setup with Intel onboard graphics and AMD discrete graphics card?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I was hoping to move my desktop machine to Xubuntu, but can't figure out how to get Ubuntu to let both my Intel HD onboard graphics driver and AMD driver operate simultaneously.

The machine runs Windows 7 and the Intel HD onboard graphics drives one monitor and the AMD Radeon card drives two monitors simultaneously. This setup works great and is very stable.

With Xubuntu, before installing the AMD driver, the Intel graphics connected monitor is active. Once the AMD driver is installed, on initial boot, the Intel graphics connected monitor is active and the other two monitors are inactive. As soon as the AMD driver loads, the Intel connected monitor becomes inactive and the other two monitors become active.

Hopefully there is an inexpensive solution. Would love to leave Windows, but I need my triple monitor setup.

Comment: `$ lspci | grep VGA   
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)   
<br/>01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]`